# JQueryUI Dialog Drag / Move Cursor Mis-Alignment in IE/Firefox

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I am trying to create the generic Message Display by using JQueryUI Dialog.

It works very well if the page is short or smaller than the user's screen.

But when the page is too long and users have to scroll, users cannot move the Dialog Box correctly.

The cursor should be on the Dialog Title bar.  Instead of that there is a distance between Title bar and actual cursor icon.  The longer the page, the bigger the distance.

Please see the screenshot.

[image]

The problem occurs only in IE and  Firefox.  It works in Google Chrome.

I have already created the test page in JSFiddle.  Sorry if my problem is confusing.  You can clearly see the problem in the JSFiddle.

http://jsfiddle.net/thetwai/6cuof2tm/

```
  $(function () {
        $("#dvDialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false
        });
    });



    ShowCustomInfoMessageBox = function (msg, title) {

        $("#dvDialog").dialog({
            title: title,
            width: 400,                
        }).dialog("open").html(msg);

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/6cuof2tm/1/

use `appendTo` option and wrap content with div {`position:relative`}

**HTML:**

```
<div id="test">
    Long Page test with JQuery UI Dialog Please scroll to botton to view Button
    <br />
    <br />Scroll to Bottom....
    <br />
    <br />....
    <div style='clear:both;'></div>
    <button onclick="ShowCustomInfoMessageBox('Try to move the dialog','test title');" style="margin-top: 700px; clear: both">Button at the bottom of the page</button>
</div>

<div id="dvDialog"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#test {
    position:relative
}
```

**JQ:**

```
 ShowCustomInfoMessageBox = function (msg, title) {

            $("#dvDialog").dialog({
                title: title,
                width: 400,
                appendTo: "#test"
            }).dialog("open").html(msg);

        }
```